# Cannot change text size in regsubsets plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to get a nice plot for my `regsubsets` output.  I need to make the font size for the x-axis labels smaller (there are 171 genes so it is unreadable).

The code I am using is:

```
regsubsets(x=genes, y=resp, really.big=TRUE, nvmax=4, nbest=10)
plot(a, scale="adjr2", cex=0.5)
```

I have several different `cex` arguments (`cex`, `cex.axis`, `cex.lab`, `cex.main`, `cex.sub`, `cex.text`, `cex.names`) and none work to make the font size smaller.

It seems like the solution should be simple but I can't figure it out!  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `plot.regsubsets` does not allow to modify anything of the x axis labels.

Have a look at code of the function: `getAnywhere("plot.regsubsets")`.

You have to modify the code of this function to change the size of the x axis labels.

```
plot.regsubsets2 <- 
function (x, labels = obj$xnames, main = NULL, scale = c("bic", 
    "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), col = gray(seq(0, 0.9, length = 10)), 
    ...) 
{
    obj <- x
    lsum <- summary(obj)
    par(mar = c(7, 5, 6, 3) + 0.1)
    nmodels <- length(lsum$rsq)
    np <- obj$np
    propscale <- FALSE
    sscale <- pmatch(scale[1], c("bic", "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), 
        nomatch = 0)
    if (sscale == 0) 
        stop(paste("Unrecognised scale=", scale))
    if (propscale) 
        stop(paste("Proportional scaling only for probabilities"))
    yscale <- switch(sscale, lsum$bic, lsum$cp, lsum$adjr2, lsum$rsq)
    up <- switch(sscale, -1, -1, 1, 1)
    index <- order(yscale * up)
    colorscale <- switch(sscale, yscale, yscale, -log(pmax(yscale, 
        1e-04)), -log(pmax(yscale, 1e-04)))
    image(z = t(ifelse(lsum$which[index, ], colorscale[index], 
        NA + max(colorscale) * 1.5)), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
        x = (1:np), y = 1:nmodels, xlab = "", ylab = scale[1], 
        col = col)
    laspar <- par("las")
    on.exit(par(las = laspar))
    par(las = 2)
    axis(1, at = 1:np, labels = labels, ...) # I modified this line
    axis(2, at = 1:nmodels, labels = signif(yscale[index], 2))
    if (!is.null(main)) 
        title(main = main)
    box()
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

Now, you can change the size of the labels:

```
library(leaps)
data(swiss)
b <- regsubsets(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss, nbest = 2)

plot.regsubsets2(b, cex.axis = 0.75)
```

[image]